# showing f is continuous at 0

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function .There are sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ such that
$x_n<0< y_n$ for all $n\geq1$, and
$f(y_n)- f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$  as $n \rightarrow \infty$. 
Then $f$ is continuous at $0$.

I have been able to show, $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(0)$ 
and $f(y_n)\rightarrow f(0)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ .
I think we will prove it by sequential criteria for which I took a sequence $\{ z_n\}$ converging to $0$, but somehow got messed up in showing $f(z_n) \rightarrow f(0)$.
Any help would be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use mathjax to typeset math.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there is some $N$ such that $f(y_N) - f(x_N) < \epsilon$. Since $z_n \to 0$ and $x_N < 0 < y_N$, we have $x_N < z_n < y_N$ for sufficiently large $n$, whence $f(x_N) \leq f(z_n) \leq f(y_N)$. Since also $f(x_N) \leq f(0) \leq f(y_N)$, we conclude that
$$
|f(z_n) - f(0)|
\leq f(y_N) - f(x_N) < \epsilon$$
as desired.